# how to get a particular tag from xml file through curl command?

Tags: xml, curl

i have a file called startup-cfg.xml containing

```
<futurePbRst>
  <fsPbProviderStpStatus>enabled</fsPbProviderStpStatus>
</futurePbRst>
<fsPbRstCVlanBridgeTable>
  <fsPbRstCVlanBridgeEntry>
    <fsPbRstPort>1</fsPbRstPort>
  </fsPbRstCVlanBridgeEntry>
</fsPbRstCVlanBridgeTable>
<fsPbRstCVlanPortInfoTable>
  <fsPbRstCVlanPortInfoEntry>
    <fsPbRstPort>1</fsPbRstPort>
    <fsPbRstCepSvid>1</fsPbRstCepSvid>
  </fsPbRstCVlanPortInfoEntry>
</fsPbRstCVlanPortInfoTable>

<interface>
  <name>eth0</name>
</interface>
<interface>
  <name>lo</name>
</interface>
<interface>
  <name>pan0</name>
</interface>
<interface>
  <name>sim0</name>
</interface>
<interface>
  <name>sim1</name>
</interface>
```

i want to fire a curl command to get a particular tag value from this xml file.how can i do it?

running the command curl http://127.0.0.1:50000/netconf/startup-cfg.xml gives the entire file contents as output.

Answer (score 0):

`curl` doesn't parse XML. Try piping `curl`'s output to `xmllint`:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:50000/netconf/startup-cfg.xml \
| xmllint --xpath '//futurePbRst/fsPbProviderStpStatus/text()' -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var=$(curl http://127.0.0.1:50000/netconf/startup-cfg.xml)
variable=$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=<particular_tag>)[^<]+" <<< "$var")
echo $variable
```